# using jQuery within asp.net control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a funny situation with a jquery selector, trying to find something within an asp.net LoginView:

Say I have 4 controls, 2 plain html `<input>`s, and 2 `<asp:TextBox>`es. One of each inside an `<asp:Loginview>`.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <input type="text" id="htmlInput1" />
        <asp:TextBox id="aspTextbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>

<input type="text" id="htmlInput2" />
<asp:TextBox id="aspTextbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then let's say I want to apply some jquery to each of them. Guess which one of these 4 does not work?

```
 <script>
         $(function () {             
             $("#htmlInput1").datepicker();
             $("#htmlInput2").datepicker();
             $("#aspTextbox1").datepicker();  
             $("#aspTextbox2").datepicker();             
         });
 </script>
```

For some reason, the asp.net textbox within the LoginView is not reached. Do I have to somehow select the LoginView first?

```
var x = $("LoginView1").....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because server-side tags are given unique identifiers when they are rendered. If you open the rendered source of the page, you'll see that the element's `id` has been modified to contain the entire control hierarchy. Because of this, your jQuery selector will no longer find the element.

However, because they will always *end* with the specified id, you can use the jQuery [`attributeEndsWith`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('[id$="aspTextbox1"]').datepicker();
```

Alternatively, give all of the elements you want to do this for a `CssClass` of `datepicker` and do:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

This is probably a cleaner, less obtrusive way of achieving the same thing, as it allows you to call the `datepicker` method on all of those elements with a single line of code. Additionally, it allows you to add *more* datepicker elements by simply giving new elements the same class, rather than having to modify your jQuery every time:

```
<asp:TextBox id="aspTextbox999" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is ASP.NET auto generates the ID at run time which is not as same as you are trying to read in jQuery . Open the viewsource and look at the ID generated. You can use that Id , otherwise if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 or higher I think you can set the Id predictable. Read this: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx
For ASP.NET control

```
          $("#"+<%= Control.ClientID %>).val();
```

Comment: `ClientIDMode` is what Devesh is talking about.